# Stop firefox from exiting execution of deferred objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, asynchronous

I've got some asynchronous code in which for a given deferred object `defObj`, I've attached several functions that I want to execute, like so:

```
$.when(defObj).done(function(){ console.log('callback 1'); });
$.when(defObj).done(function(){ console.log('callback 2'); });
$.when(defObj).done(function(){ console.log('callback 3'); });
```

(In the actual code, these are attached in a few different functions that I'm calling to initialize a page.)

After some other asynchronous code finishes, I want to resolve the deferred object and trigger all of the callbacks. I manually resolve the callback:

```
defObj.resolve();
```

In chrome, this works fine. The deferred object resolves and all of the callbacks fire. In firefox, I get an error of some sort in the second callback (or at least, I assume I do, since it doesn't show up in the console.) This error blocks the rest of the deferred objects from resolving, and stops execution of the code. I tried putting the code in a try/catch block:

```
try{ defObj.resolve(); } catch(e){ console.error(e) };
```

but firefox doesn't make it into the catch block.

Is there a way of stopping firefox from exiting code execution before it finishes all of the deferred callbacks?

Let me know if this seems unclear and I'll try to clean it up.

Comment: have you tried `$.when(defObj).done(function(){ try {console.log('callback 2');} catch (e) {console.log "Error in callback 2";} });`

Comment: Works for me as it should.

Comment: Just a comment: `$.when()` is meant more for joining several promises together. You can just do `defObj.done` rather than `$.when(defObj).done`

Comment: I ended up using a `window.setTimeout` block to remove the code that was causing firefox to stop execution.

Answer (score 0):

I tried encapsulating the code in a `try{}catch(){}` block, but to no avail. What ended up working was moving the code that was breaking into an asynchronous code block with a `window.setTimeout` call with a time delay of zero, like so:

```
$.when(defObj).done(function(){ console.log('callback 1'); });
$.when(defObj).done(function(){
    window.setTimeout(function(){console.log('callback 2'); }, 0); 
});
$.when(defObj).done(function(){ console.log('callback 3'); });
```

This takes the code that was causing the problem out of the flow of the rest of the page, which stops it from blocking the execution. I still have no idea what is causing firefox to stop code execution, but this is a decent way around it.

Comment: We might be able to help you come up with a real answer if you showed us the offending code.

Comment: The actual code of the function that's killing firefox is about 800 lines. I didn't want to inflict that on SO :)

Comment: I seriously doubt all 800 lines are causing this problem.

Comment: As do I, but I haven't had time to dig through and isolate the exact problem. 800 lines is what I've isolated it to. For now I just wanted to stop whatever that problem is from affecting the rest of the code.